# Finding critical points of $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2+x^2y+4$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I want to check whether if everything is correct or not. So, we have:

$f_{x}=2x+2y$
$f_y= 2y+x^2$. Then, $f_x=f_y=0 \implies (0,0),(\sqrt 2,-1)(-\sqrt2,-1)$ are the critical points.

Also, $f_{xx}=2+2y, f_{xy}=f_{yx}=2x, f_{yy}=2$. Using these, we have the determinant D of Hessian matrix $D=4(1+y-x^2)$.

At $(0,0)$ we have $D=4 >0$. So it is local minimum.

At $(\sqrt 2,-1)$ we have $D = 4(1-1-2) = -8 <0$.

At $(-\sqrt 2,-1)$ we have $D = 4(1-1-2) = -8 <0$. So $(\sqrt 2,-1)(-\sqrt2,-1)$  are saddle point.

Is this solution correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in $f_x$ -- you wrote $2y$ instead of $2xy$ (clearly only a typo because you treated it correctly as $2xy$ in the remainder of the answer).

That aside, looks good!